# Python check if dict is part of other dict

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

i have 2 dict's  with the same keys

```
dict1 = {'version': 222,'name_app': 'foo1'}
dict2 = {'version': 222,'name_app': 'foo1','dir': 'c','path': 'cc'}
```

Now I like to check if dict1 have the same keys and values as dict2
I like to avoid doing loops and check each key and value in dict1 is in dict 2
is there any pythonic elegant way to do that?
**UPDATE**
both keys of dict1 most be in dict 2 if only 1 match it is false

Comment: I read python trick book written by dan Badler, I haven't run into something like that. I think you have to use loops or generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```py
from operator import itemgetter

dict1 = {"version": 222, "name_app": "foo1"}
dict2 = {"version": 222, "name_app": "foo1", "dir": "c", "path": "cc"}

g = itemgetter(*dict1)
print(g(dict1) == g(dict2))
```

Prints:

```py
True
```

---

EDIT: All keys of dict1 must be matched:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

dict1 = {"version": 222, "name_app": "foo1"}
dict2 = {"version": 222, "name_app": "foo1", "dir": "c", "path": "cc"}

g = itemgetter(*dict1)
print(dict1.keys() <= dict2.keys() and g(dict1) == g(dict2))
```

Prints:

```py
True
```

EDIT2: If dict has a list value:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

dict1 = {"version": 222, "name_app": ["a", "b", "c"]}
dict2 = {"version": 222, "name_app": ["a", "b", "c"], "dir": "c", "path": "cc"}

g = itemgetter(*dict1)
print(dict1.keys() <= dict2.keys() and g(dict1) == g(dict2))
```

Prints:

```
True
```

Comment: also updated the question all keys of dict1 must be matched

Comment: Thanks , but now i have another problem, as it is not in this question 
Its breaks if the dict have key with list value

Comment: @user63898 My answer works with values as a list. See edit2.

Comment: yeah i see , give you the current answer thanks!

Comment: is there any way to make the values of the dict2 lower case ?

Comment: @user63898 Yes, there's a way, but it involves explicit for loop (to make all keys of dict2 lower case)

Comment: any way to lower case only the keys that exist in dict1? not entire dict2 ?

Comment: @user63898 To not clutter the comment section, I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253220/python-lower-case-dict-values-before-comparing-2-dicts-using-itemgetter

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this

```
set(dict1.items())-set(dict2.items())== set()
```

It will return true or false according to your condition

If dictonaries have lists:

```
from operator import *
g = itemgetter(*dict1)
print(dict1.keys() <= dict2.keys() and g(dict1) == g(dict2))
```

Comment: only problem is when the dict contains list then it will not work and will give :
{TypeError}unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: then you can do it using itemgetter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
dict1 = {'version': 222,'name_app': 'foo1'}
dict2 = {'version': 222,'name_app': 'for','dir': 'c','path': 'cc'}
common=set(dict1.items())-set(dict2.items())
print(list(common)!=[])
```

Comment: also updated the question all keys of dict1 must be matched 
in your example its even  if 1 key match return true