# Python lower case dict values before comparing 2 dicts using itemgetter

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison, lowercase

i compare 2 dicts dict1 keys and values must be in dict2
The problem is the in dict2 the values are in upper case and i like to lower case them before comparing them. if it possible to not loop the entire dict2 but only the relevant keys

```
dict1 = {'version': 'fff', 'ff':1,'name_app': ['for']}
dict2 = {'version': 'FFF', 'ff':1,'name_app': ['for'], 'dir': 'c', 'path': 'cc'}
g = itemgetter(*dict1)
if(g(dict1) == g(dict2)):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

in this example i like to lower case only version key in dict2 , but it can be more then 1 key

Comment: Can the `['for']` in `dict2` be upper case as well?

Comment: leave it as it for now, only the literal strings value for now

Comment: How is it possible for you to write such a poor question when you have so much reputation? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

dict1 = {"version": "fff", "ff": 1, "name_app": ["for"]}
dict2 = {
    "version": "FFF",
    "ff": 1,
    "name_app": ["for"],
    "dir": "c",
    "path": "cc",
}
g = itemgetter(*dict1)

if g(dict1) == tuple(
    map(lambda x: x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else x, g(dict2))
):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Prints:

```
True
```

Comment: can you explain please what you did here ?

Comment: @user63898 With `g(dict2)` I get values from `dict2` and check if these values are strings. If they are strings I convert them to lowercase. Then compare them to values from `dict1`

Comment: why the Tuple ?

Comment: @user63898 `operator.itemgetter` returns the values in form of tuple. So I need to compare them as two tuples.